# Java - ¿Cómo usar una clase genérica para representar una concreta?

Tags: java

Tengo dos clases *Task* y *Project*, y quiero usar una tercera, p.e. Xxx, para obtener ciertos datos con un formato determinado.
Como no se que tipo de clase va a recibir la clase Xxx, quiero inyectarle en el constructor un tipo genérico, como Object.
En función del tipo de la instancia, hago un cast al tipo concreto de la instancia inyectada.

Ahora en teoría no debería haber problema al llamar al método para obtener los datos con el formato de salida, ya que la instancia si debería tener ese método, pero el IDE me marca como error, ya que la instancia de la clase Object, a la que estoy llamando (aunque le hice el cast al guardarla), no tiene definidos ese métodos.

No se si me explico.

Código *(simplificado para la pregunta)*:

```
public class MiClass {

    /******************************************************************/
    /*** Properties declaration ***************************************/

        private Object obj;


    /******************************************************************/
    /*** Methods declaration ******************************************/

        /**
         * Constructor
         *
         * @param  obj -> instance of Task or Project
         */
        public MiClass(Object obj) {
            this.set(obj);
        }

        /**
         * Gets the customized string
         *
         * @return
         */
        public String getFinalDate() {
            long fDate = this.obj.getFinalDate();

            if (fDate > 0) {
                return "Final date: "
                    + DateUtils.getStrDate(fDate);
            }

            return "No 'final date' setted for this project.";
        }

        /**
         * Sets a new instance of X
         *
         * @param obj
         */
        public final void set(Object obj) {
            if (this.obj instanceof Project) {
                this.obj = (Project) this.obj;
            } else {
                this.obj = (Task) this.obj;
            }
        }


} // class
```

La solución que tengo es ***usar una superclase*** de *Task* y *Project* ***en lugar de Object***. Esta clase define los métodos comunes y no hay problema, pero estoy obligado también a que defina los métodos concretos, por ejemplo que solo estan en *Project*, e implementarlos en esta clase. **¿Hay otra solución?**

Comment: Veo que aceptas un porcentaje sorprendentemente bajo de respuestas...

Comment: @SJuan76 una vez me dijeron lo contrario. Te ponen una respuesta que te parece supercorrecta y luego no lo es tanto, pero la aceptaste... En general prefiero, votar positivamente y dar unos días a ver si aparecen soluciones interesantes, o más bien espero a tener algún rato libre para revisar las respuestas más detenidamente.

Answer (score 0):

1. La superclase no tiene porqué definir todos los métodos, solo aquellos que se usen `MiClass`. Otros métodos especificos de `Project` y `Task` se pueden definir en las respectivas clases. Como en el case de `Object`, dichos métodos solo se podrán invocar mediante una referencia de la subclase adecuada.
2. Si no quieres que la superclase defina una **implementación** de los métodos, puedes hacerla `abstract` (no se puede crear una instancia, y se pueden dejar métodos declarados pero cuya implementación deberá hacerse en subclases) o usar una `interface`.
3. Por último, y solo para evitar que a alguien se le ocurra y piense que es buena idea, puedes poner en `MiClass` un atributo de cada tipo y asignar en el constructor según el valor de `instanceof`. Luego accedes a los valores comprobando qué atributo tiene valor.

   MUY DESACONSEJABLE, es un código muy feo y te obliga a modificar `MiClass` si te aparece una nueva clase relacionada, mientras que con una superclase o interface te basta con crear una nueva subclase que cumpla el contrato de la superclase.

En general, si se trata de que ambas clases ofrecen métodos comunes pero no son generalizaciones de un mismo tipo, se tira más hacia definir interfaces que no superclases.

Un ejemplo sería `Empleado` y `Cliente` ambas teniendo un `getDireccion()`. Aunque tengan esto en común, representan conceptos suficientemente distintos que lo que se suele hacer es definir un interface (p.ej. `Direccionable`) que defina el método `getDireccion()` y hacer que ambas clases lo implementen.

Comment: `Por último, y solo para evitar que a alguien se le ocurra y piense que es buena idea...` ¿es o no buena idea usar el la solución del punto 3? No me queda claro... Parece una opción viable aunque tengo que poner algunos condicionales adicionales.

Comment: Esos "algunos condicionales adicionales" complican tu código, tanto para escribirlo (riesgo de introducir errores), leerlo (entender qué hace y mantenerlo) y hacer juegos de pruebas que incluyan todas las posibilidades. Adicionalmente, rompe con el [principio abierto-cerrado](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principio_de_abierto/cerrado) una nueva clase tendrás que modificar `MiClass`. Por último, impide que puedas restringir el tipo del parámetro, necesitarás seguir aceptando un `Object` en lugar de `MiInterfaz` o `MiSuperClase`. Muchos inconvenientes y ninguna ventaja.

Comment: Hay buenas prácticas y formas de hacer las cosas (SOLID, abierto/cerrado, encapsulación, etc.) porque se sabe que si el código se complica apareceran errores, y por eso las buenas prácticas te guían hacía el código de más calidad.

Comment: Ok, el punto 3, sería la solución mala. Se poco o nada se SOLID, pero sí entiendo que añadir complejidad al código es malo. Entiendo que lo mejor sería crear una *Interface*, porque la superclase ya estaba definida, y de otro modo y en este caso me obligó a añadir definiciones de métodos a esta cuando creo ***MiClase***, y si creará otras clases que requieran fuera de los usos previstos inicialmente, y no sería lo deseable...

Comment: Sí, interface. La última parte del comentario no lo entiendo.

Answer (score 0):

¿Por qué no una interfaz que únicamente declare los métodos que vas a usar? La he llamado `Assignment`, pero es cosa tuya buscar un nombre adecuado:

```
public interface Assignment {
    // este es el unico metodo que parece que es comun
    long getFinalDate();
}

public class Project implements Assignment { 
    // task esta definido de manera similar

}
```

Así en tu clase `MiClass` puedes usar `Assignment` y te olvidas del método `set`:

```
public class MiClass {

    private Assignment assignment;

    public MiClass(Assignment assignment) {
        this.assignment = assignment;
    }

    public String getFinalDate() {
        long fDate = this.assignment.getFinalDate();

        if (fDate > 0) {
            return "Final date: "
                    + DateUtils.getStrDate(fDate);
        }

        return "No 'final date' setted for this project.";
    }


    // no se necesita el metodo set

}
```